# How has the number of Stack Overflow users changed over time?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, users

I am curious to know if there exists any detailed information about how the number of users have developed since the launch of the Stack Overflow webpage until now. More specifically the number of users from year to year.

Comment: Pretty sure there's a data explorer query for this, depending on exactly what you want. Someone might oblige you on that if you include some more detail.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/80302/new-users-per-day

Comment: And to go with @Stijn, http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/150515/number-of-users-created-per-year is something I whipped together for number of registered users per year

Comment: Or even better, use the [quantcast stats](https://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc/traffic/sites)

Comment: Perfect, most appreciated.!

Comment: @StevenV: You mean the number of **new** registrations every year.

Comment: @juergend Ah yes, very important distinction. Good to point that out.

Comment: https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?country=USI think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @StevenV You can probably post that as an answer (just [swap the fields around](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/150652/number-of-users-created-per-year) so you get a nice graph, and post the results in the answer, along with the graph).

Comment: @Dynamic [no, not really](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NdGUr.png). Even when it's working it's only measuring **visits/hits** not amount of users so it's really not relevant.